# How to use Symfony 4.1 Security / Authentication Providers without Doctrine / ORM

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony4

In my current app, we've chosen not to use Doctrine or an ORM.  I'm attempting to use Symfony 4.1's authentication system to log people in.  What I'd like to do is use PDO directly to fetch users from the database.

I'm following this guide:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html.  In `security.yaml`, I've created a new `provider` entry and added it to the firewall:

```
providers:
    db_provider:
        id: App\Utility\Security\UserAuthenticationProvider
encoders:
    App\Utility\Security\UserAuthenticationProvider: bcrypt
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: check_login
            default_target_path: user
        anonymous: ~
        provider: db_provider
```

And I've created `UserAuthenticationProvider`:

```
class UserAuthenticationProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    private $config;
    private $userDAO;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->config = new Config();
        $this->userDAO = new MySqlUserDAO($this->config);
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
        $user = $this->userDAO->getUserByUsername();
        ...
        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
        ...
    }

    public function supportsClass($class) {
        ...
    }
```

My `userDAO` returns an object that implements `UserInterface`.

So when I got to my route `/login`, I get my login form.  However, no users are loaded from the database.  I can see that my UserProviderInterface gets created (by using `dump` in the constructor), but `loadUserByUsername` does not.

Do I need to implement something else that uses my `UserAuthenticationProvider` and calls `loadUserByUsername`?

Is there perhaps a better way to do authentication in Symfony without using Doctrine?

**UPDATE**

I found [this guide](https://matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-how-to-create-a-userprovider/) which is older but has a bit more detail / context.

I've changed my classes / configs like so (edited for brevity):

```
#security.yaml
security:
    providers:
        db_provider:
            id: database_user_provider

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: db_provider
                login_path: login
                check_path: check_login
                default_target_path: do_some_stuff
```

.

```
#services.yaml
services:
    database_user_provider:
        class: App\Utility\Security\DatabaseUserProvider
```

.

```
class DatabaseUser
    implements
        UserInterface,
        EquatableInterface
{
    protected $user;

    public function getUser(): User  {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user): void  {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        return array("ROLE_USER");
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->getUser()->getPassword();
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->getUser()->getUsername();
    }
}
```

.

```
class DatabaseUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    private $config;
    private $userDAO;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->config = new Config();
        $this->userDAO = new MySqlUserDAO($this->config);
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username): UserInterface {            
        $user = $this->userDAO->getUserByUsername($username);            
        $dbUser = new DatabaseUser();
        $dbUser->setUser($user);

        return $dbUser;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {            
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class) {
        return DatabaseUser::class === $class;
    }
}
```

So what each file is doing (in a nutshell is):

services.yaml:  naming my class `DatabaseUserProvider` to the service name `database_user_provider` for use in security.yaml.

security.yaml:  setting `database_user_provider` to the alias `db_provider` and adding that as the provider on the `main` firewall.

DatabaseUser:  my 'entity' class to represent my user from the database.  I have a dumb `User` class that just has a few properties (username, password) and getters / setters for those.  It is set as a property for the `DatabaseUser` object.

DatabaseUserProvider:  Loads my DatabaseUser objects from the database using the DAO and returns them.  (more specifically, the DAO returns a user, which is added to a new DatabaseUser object, which is returned).

The DAO simply runs a sql query to get a single result from the user table.  it then takes this result and populates a `User` Value Object and returns it.

**Results**

When I was using Doctrine (and following this guide for [loading users from the database](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html) and [this one for a login form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html)), the login route on the `SecurityController` would handle both rendering of the form and processing of the login request.  Somehow, Symfony / Doctrine was smart enough to automatically (using a listener maybe???) load the appropriate user entity from the DB and authenticate them against the password they provided (and then set the user token and redirect them to the page they were trying to access.)

When I bypass doctrine (and use my own DAOs) and the classes above, authentication still does not occur.  I can see that an instance of `DatabaseUserProvider` is being created (by dumping some vars in the constructor), and the Security tab of the profilier shows `database_user_provider` as the provider.  But that seems to be as far as it gets.

**Question**

It seems to me that `DatabaseUserProvider::loadUserByUsername` should be the next thing that should happen.  From where does this method get called from?  Do I need to be passing the username into the constructor and kick it off from there?  Should I be using this class as a service in my Controller and call the method manually from the controller (something I did not have to do when using doctrine - none of this logic was in the controller)?

Comment: Try to use guard, it is easy to use and create for independent needs. 

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

And doctrine isn't related, it's just ORM )

Comment: I assume you área using the right params for the auth request, like _username and _password, right?

Comment: This is not part of your issue, but will probably be one in the later steps. You have to specify the User-class when you define the encoders and you point it to the user provider instead. It should probably be something like `App\...\MySqlUserDAO: bcrypt`

Comment: "when I got to my route /login" does that mean you submitted the data? If so, you can the profiler toolbar at the bottom of the page. It has a Security panel that should give you some information like which firewall was recognized and what provider was attempted to call. Your provider looks a bit weird though. I can't tell what dao-class is doing and instead of calling a method `->getUserByUsername` is just a property? Maybe you should write some tests for that provider to see if it work as expected in isolation

Comment: @dbrumann /login presents the form, and also is the form action, so yes, data will have been submitted at that point.  `getUserByUsername` is an error... should be a method... corrected.